# Issues adding multi-threading to a script

Tags: powershell

I've made a script to check client gateways for open ports, which works great but takes forever to run.  So I'm trying to split the work into threads to make the work go faster.

The issue I seem to be having is that when I do a Get-Job | Receive-Job it claims that -Port has a value of 0

Adding/removing -ArgumentList $gateway, $port (or just port) doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

I originally tried with Invoke-Comment to limit the number of jobs, but I've reverted to just trying to get this to work.

```
$gateways = Import-CSV '.\perlaw.csv'
$ports = 22, 80, 8080, 443, 4443, 3389
foreach ($gateway in $gateways){
$scriptblock = {foreach ($port in $ports){
    $result = Test-NetConnection $gateway.'connection gateway' -Port $port;

    $out =  @(
        $gateway.'group id',
        $gateway.'connection gateway',
        $port
    )
    $output = "{0}, {1}, {2}" -f $out
    if ($result.TcpTestSucceeded -eq 'True'){
        Out-File -FilePath .\$($gateway.'group id').csv -InputObject 
$output -NoClobber -Append;
    }
}

}
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $gateways, $ports
}
```

I'm expecting this to iterate through the list of gateways, and each port for that gateway, test the combinations, and output results to a file.

This works when single-threaded, when adding multi-threading the jobs instantly complete and nothing is written to the file.  If I alter the jobs to make a job per port running Get/Receive-Job shows port as 0 no matter what I pipe in.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: If you pass arguments to a job, you have to add code to the job to receive them, just as it is done in a function. Add `param ($gateway, $ports)`.at the beginning of the scriptblock Another thing: call the job with $argument, not $arguments. That way I got the jobs running. But within the job things go wrong too. Maybe here my testing env is the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned earlier in my comment parameters had to be added to the job. Another thing is that jobs are not necessarily started in the same directory as where the script is invoked. So the .csv file are not created where you might expect them.  So I added a parameter for that as well.

This works (on my machine):

```
$gateways = Import-CSV '.\perlaw.csv'
$ports = 22, 80, 8080, 443, 4443, 3389
foreach ($gateway in $gateways) {
    $scriptblock = {
        param (
            $gateway,
            $ports,
            $path
        )
        foreach ($port in $ports) {
            $result = Test-NetConnection $gateway.'connection gateway' -Port $port;

            $out = @(
                $gateway.'group id',
                $gateway.'connection gateway',
                $port
            )
            $output = "{0}, {1}, {2}" -f $out

            if ($result.TcpTestSucceeded) {
                Out-File -FilePath $path\$($gateway.'group id').csv -InputObject $output -NoClobber -Append;
            }
        }

    }
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -ArgumentList $gateway, $ports, (Get-Location).Path
}
```